# Check whether a song has finished playing in pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Is there any way to tell whether a song has finished playing in pygame?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame

root = Tk()
pygame.init()

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load("test.ogg")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = 0)

def pause():
    global paused
    if paused == False:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        paused = True
    elif paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused = False

def check_if_finished():
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        print("Song is not finished")
    else:
        print("Song is finshed")

paused = False

play_button = Button(root , text = "Play Song" , command = play)
play_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

pause_button = Button(root , text = "Pause Song" , command = pause)
pause_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 15)

check_button = Button(root , text = "Check" , command = check_if_finished)
check_button.grid(row = 2 , column = 0)

mainloop()
```

Here, I used the `pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()` function to check whether the song has finished, but the problem is that the `check_if_finished()` function is not giving me the expected output when I pause the song. What I want is to not print `"The song is finished"` when I pause the song.

Is there any way to achieve this in pygame?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to not print "The song is finished" when I pause the song.

You are right. See [`pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html):

> Returns True when the music stream is actively playing. When the music is idle this returns False. In pygame 2.0.1 and above this function **returns False when the music is paused**.

You can deal with this by simply adding an additional condition:

```py
def check_if_finished():

    if paused or pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        print("Song is not finished")
    else:
        print("Song is finshed")`
```